# Sorting algorithms in Ruby sorting only by first digit

Tags: ruby, algorithm

So I've been implementing a few different sorting methods (quick, merge, and insertion) and came across seemed a tad bit impractical and was wondering if someone could explain the thought process behind the behavior.

The list im trying to sort is the following:

```
[20401, 11087, 2, 62176, 70095, 20947, 20098, 90914, 53475, 51251, 20065]
```

The feedback is:

```
["11087", "2", "20065", "20098", "20401", "20947", "51251", "53475", "62176", "70095", "90914"]
```

If I change the 2 over to 00002 then I get a properly sorted list

```
["00002", "11087", "20065", "20098", "20401", "20947", "51251", "53475", "62176", "70095", "90914"]
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: can you show your code, it looks a bit fishy that your output is converted to a string in which case the sequence is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The respective two outputs that you are demostrating in the OP can be obtained as follows:

```
a = [20401, 11087, 2, 62176, 70095, 20947, 20098, 90914, 53475, 51251, 20065]

a.sort.map &"%05d".method( :% )
#=> ["00002", "11087", "20065", "20098", "20401", "20947", "51251", "53475", "62176", "70095", "90914"]

a.map( &:to_s ).sort
#=> ["11087", "2", "20065", "20098", "20401", "20947", "51251", "53475", "62176", "70095", "90914"]
```

Now what was the question, again?